# Weird issue with changing text color using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I am having a weird issue that I somehow cannot seem to fix. If there is an error, I am trying to display text saying there's an error (which does work), however, I want that text to be red and everything I have tried has not worked.

I have tried to set the color to red in the div tag of which i am changing the innerHTML however that does not work. I have also tried to change it in javascript, doesn't work. And also add a style parameter in the h2 tag I am adding, you guessed it, doesn't work.

Any ideas what the issue is?

JS

```
    var error_handle = document.getElementById('error-handle');

.then(
    (message) => {if(message != "OK"){
        error_handle.innerHTML = "<h4  id ='errortag';'>An error has occured while sending the email. Please try again.</h4>"
        error_handle.style.color = "#e3121d";

        confirmation.innerHTML = "";
        button.value = "Send Message";

    }});
```

HTML

```
<div id ="error-handle">

</div>
```

CSS

```
#error-handle {color: "r#e3121d'"; background-color: '#e3121d';}
#errortag{font-family: "Mukta Mahee", arial, sans-serif;color: '#e3121d';}
```

Comment: Why does your color value have an `r` in it? `color: "r#e3121d'"`

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS change: `"r#e3121d'";` to `"#e3121d";`

P.S. This is my first time answering a question on Stackoverflow please correct me if I'm wrong :).

Comment: Wow I feel stupid. The problem was I had the hex code in quotes when it isn't supposed to be. So that fixed it.

Comment: @MaxGertner If it's fixed consider marking this answer as 'Accepted'